# Delete period preceded by only one character

Tags: awk, sed, period

How can I delete a period preceded by only one character?

I'm looking for a one line `sed` or `awk` code.

The target line is: (the target pattern I want to delete is in `**Bold stackoverflow code ***j.*** **`)

```
xxx-xxx, **j.** c., univ los xxx, res grp porous solid \& calorimetry, dept chem, fac sci, bogota, colombia.
```

and the result I'm looking for:

```
xxx-xxx, c., univ los xxx, res grp porous solid \& calorimetry, dept chem, fac sci, bogota, colombia.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed 's/ [a-zA-Z]\./ /g' <filename>` will work if you are sure that these characters will not appear at the start of the line and that all such characters will be preceded by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what you want.
But this is slightly more robust than the other proposal:

```
sed 's/\b\w\.//g'
```

Both however also delete the ".c"...